# What's the best way to write directives?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I've been struggling with the way to implement a good structure for directives in TypeScript. I've found couple of solutions online, however to be honest, I have no idea which one to use - they all do their job.

What is a good structure for a directive to stick to?

n.b. I'm using AngularJS 1.

Comment: Are you asking for AngularJS in general, for the v1 or v2 ?

Comment: I am asking about AngularJS v1 :)

Comment: Directives in general are a tricky concept. It really depends on what you're trying to do with them if you should even try to make one work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opininion, thinking on Typescript Way, you need to import the *[AngularJS definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs)*, this gives you references on the framework.

1. Create a Module
2. Export a Function that returns a *[Angular Directive Definition Object](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)*
3. In **ddo** use the APIs as you wish

   [...] export function tsDirective():  **ng.IDirective** [...]